# subscribe method is not working in Angular

Tags: angular

[image: 1]

I'm working on Angular project integrated with .net core 6
the problem is that I want to get the last order of the user to view it in his profile, so I created a service as follows

```
GetAllOrders(userId:string){
        return this.http.get<ResultViewModel>(environment.apiURl+"OrderAPI/Get?userId="+userId);
    }
```

and in my profile.ts I call a function called getLastOrder()

```
 getLastOrder(){
  this.order.GetAllOrders(this.id).subscribe(res=>{
    console.log(res.data)
    this.Order=res.data.data[0];
  },err=>console.log(err) )
 }
```

anything written in subscribe is not working, even if the data is returned from backend correctly

I call this function in onInit

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.profileInfo()
    this.form=this.builder.group(
      {
        NameEN:['',[Validators.required]],
        NameAR:['',[Validators.required]],
        Role:['',[Validators.required]],
        Email:['',[Validators.required]],
        Phone:['',[Validators.required]],

    });
    this.getLastOrder();

  }
```

notes:
profile info function which gets user info and edit function that updates info are working correctly.

Is that happened because of multiple HTTP requests?
I hope I made it clear. Thanks in advance
Update:
I found the request is pending forever. how can I solve that?

Comment: Can you share a screenshoot of what's your browser developper console are showing on the network tab?

Comment: I edited the question and add a screenshot

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @b.g can you please show how you have used it on HTML? like ({{ Order }}), and also show what is response returned from API.

Comment: Please do a `console.log(res)` instead of `console.log(res.data)`